# Attempting to Share Internet through PC, to Wireless Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Alright, as the Title suggests, I am attempting to connect my PC(1) to Wifi(1) and then ethernet it to Wifi(2) and get internet to PC(2) wirelessly.

So far, I have reset the Wifi(2) and made it all dynamic as several other threads ive found have said. I have Internet from Wifi(1) on PC(1) and I have the connection bridged the the Ethernet port, I know that it is working as I am able to see Devices that are connected to Wifi(1). However I am not able to get Internet on PC(2)

Comment: If you have bridged the wifi and eth ports on your PC, then there should be no DHCP on wifi 2 and you should be connecting to a LAN port.  Is that the case?  If so, PC2 should have an IP range in the DHCP scope set up on Wifi 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you're using, so I can't give very specific instructions, but generally speaking it looks like you want to use Internet Connection Sharing (as Microsoft calls it; different OSes may use different names) instead of bridging. This will increase the amount of work your PC(1) has to do - it will essentially be acting as a router, with DHCP and DNS servers, plus performing network address translation - but will work even if your upstream connection (WiFi(1) or above) only allows a single client.

I've confirmed that sharing a WiFi connection via Ethernet works on Windows Vista and up. It doesn't work on XP - XP would always insist that if one of the connections was wired, that must be the one you're trying to share - but hopefully nobody is using that obsolete POS anymore. If you're using OS X, there used to be an issue with their connection sharing - the DHCP server wouldn't correctly report the DNS address, so you had to enter it manually on the shared-to device - but that was a few years (and versions of OS X) ago and is hopefully fixed now. On Linux... good luck? I've heard of it working, and it *should* work, but I haven't personally done that particular combo on any distro.